# Подключение 4х видов шрифта

Tags: шрифты, css

Возникла такая сложность: через css нужно подключить один и тот же шрифт (в 4 файлах). Например 1-`classic`, 2 - `bold`, 3 - `italic`, 4 - `bolditalic`. Как их подключить и вызывать их для параграфов в 4 возможных вариантах??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй для каждого начертания свое название шрифта:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFontClassic; 
    src: url(fonts/MyFontClassic.ttf); 
   }
```